# Creating JS Files using php

Tags: php, jquery, makefile

I have a code like this which is created using php

```
<?php
$script="$(document).ready(function(){alert('hai');});";
?>
```

As far as I have referred in other websites, they have used fopen() and fwrite() to open a text file and write in it. I don't want txt file to be created.Can I create a script file say script.js that contains data in the $script variable using php?

Comment: just have the php script file print out the script code, and then in like your <script> tag make `src` point to your php script. Make sure to do a `header('Content-Type: text/javascript');` before hand so browser will interpret it correctly.

Comment: It is not static.The js code created varies. so I have to create each js file whenever the php file is executed

Comment: which is why you point it at the php script, and do the processing that needs done in the script before printing out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will create file called `script.js` and contains your JS statements:

```
$script="$(document).ready(function(){alert('hai');});";
$fileName="script.js";
file_put_contents($fileName, $script);
```

Comment: please rename the variable name $file to $filename

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like..

file_put_contents()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Otherwise im not sure what you are asking.

Comment: It copies and append code from one file to another. But I have to create a fresh js file whenever the php file is executed

Comment: you can do that excatly with my script... u do need to modify it to what you need excatly, since i do not really understand what you need i cant do much else.  But i think another also made a comment.  maybe that is more what you need :-)  Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for your solution. file_put_contents() creates a file directly.Instead of copying from another text file, we need to write our data and create it. I have marked the right answer above. That is what the solution I expected.